# dbt docs generate failing on circleci

Tags: dbt

I see this error:

```
dbt docs generate --profiles-dir ***** --project-dir *****
Running with dbt=0.20.2
[WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 4 unused configuration paths:
- models.data_vault.raw_vault.link
- models.data_vault.raw_vault.sat
- models.data_vault.raw_vault.t_link
- models.data_vault.business_vault

Found 30 models, 7 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 461 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 28 sources, 0 exposures

ERROR: Database Error
  timeout expired
  
make: *** [Makefile:36: docs-circle] Error 1
```

What is the database error? Why is it timing out? Why is a database needed here for `dbt docs generate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
What is the database error?
```

It is a timeout error

```
Why is it timing out?
```

No way we can know that without knowing details about your db or configurations and network.

```
Why is a database needed here for dbt docs generate?
```

The `dbt docs generate` command will go and run a bunch of SQL against your database to get metadata about your sources. For example, if your target/profile is Redshift, it'll go query rowcount, table size, sort keys, dist style, stats, etc. from the system tables.

Comment: I see circle just doesn't have permission access to redshift, that's likely why. but redshift is in my VPN so this gets harder